# Why is it Soifon didn't know about Shunkō?

Tags: bleach

After Rukia is rescued and everyone is off fighting battles, during their fight Soifon says she developed a new technique which she only just perfected and hasn't even gotten a name.

however Yoruichi says it does have a name calling it Shunkō, she even explains that the reason why the Stealth Force's attire is designed the way it is is because of how Shunkō works and that fabric on the arms and back would be blown away.

Yoruichi is Soifon's mentor and took her place as head of the Stealth Force when Yoruichi disappeared. if Shunkō was developed between Yoruichi and Urahara after they left then the design of the Stealth Force's attires wouldn't be so linked to it.

So how come Soifon didn't know about Shunkō?

Comment: Why do she must know about it? A comparison from Kungfu stories, most of the time the mentor in Kungfu stories didn't and won't teach all of his techniques to his pupil.

Comment: @AyaseEri the kungfu stuff i have seen/read (which may not be a lot compared to other things i read/watch) generally show that the pupil still knows about the moves their mentor teach them and end up learning it on their own or even surpassing the move by defeating it. also i'm not asking why Yoruichi didn't teach it to Soifon since she explains this but rather why Soifon, being the leader of the Stealth Force who's attire is implied to be designed for Shunkō didn't know it even existed and assumed she invented it

Comment: Yoruichi was the inventor of Shunko. So of course if Soi Fon doesn't know about Shunko, then it means Yoruichi never taught her about it, or never use it in front of her.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was stated in the same episode that it was revealed.  Yoruichi explained to Soifon that she did not want to teach Shunko to her because it was too unstable (if I recall correctly), with Yoruichi stating "Even I can't control it."

Edit: I did not read all the comments under your question and did not see that you already knew that much, here is the rest of my answer;  This also explains why Soifon would never have witnessed Yoruichi using the technique, because it was unsuitable for battle.